# Convert animated grease pencil stroke into geometry, keeping animation

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

I have been asked to do several animations of a line that animates onto the screen left to right then kind of vibrates into a piece of handwriting. I did a test which was just one word and I kind of eyeballed it in After Effects. But now they want some longer lines and I'm finding it very arduous and AE is very bad at this, it seems, when there are a lot of control points to edit.

So in Blender, in *Grease Pencil*, I can make a nice morph between a straightish line and some handwriting but I would like to then apply a *Wave* warp modifier to it for a vibration effect but this is only available for meshes. If I convert my GP animated line to a mesh I lose the animation.

I thought I might be able to export to Alembic but that doesn't seem to work and it comes back in as an empty object.

Is this is possible in Blender?

Comment: Maybe *Effects > Wave Distortion* is what you are looking for ? Works only in *Viewport Shading > Rendered*. I don't know much about grease pencil.